# SSH copy command is returning exit code 1

Tags: ssh, file-copy

I am using `ssh` to copy files from one directory to another, but I get the following error when doing so:

```
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [cp /usr/local/jboss/server/deploy/somewarfile.war /opt/jboss/backups/somewarfile.war] ... 
SSH: EXEC: connected cp: cannot stat `/usr/local/jboss/server/deploy/somewarfile.war': No such file or directory 
SSH: EXEC: completed after 201 ms ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [1]]
```

Is there any way to make the copy command return exit status 0 if the file does not exist?

Comment: You really should show us the command you actually typed. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is stating that the specified source file for the `cp` command does not exist, which is why `cp` is returning an error code.  Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: The file does not exist, but, I need the cp to not return exit code of 1 when there is no file. I'm using a plugin for Jenkins which stops executing the ssh script when it sees anything other than 0 status code.

Comment: `cp` will not return a nonzero exit code when the source file does not exist, by design.  If you want to capture an expected error, you can use the construct `cp foo bar || :`, which will "consume" the error code.  However, this will also consume the error code for any other error conditions of that command.

Comment: Is that an actual command? Will my command become `cp /usr/local/jboss/server/deploy/somewarfile.war /opt/jboss/backups/somewarfile.war || :`  ?

Comment: Quite so, the `||` shell operator tells the shell "If the first command fails, run the second command"; `:` is a no-op which is a vestige from when it used to demark a destination for a goto command.